# How to prevent firing click function from all posts in WordPress post page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am using following jQuery for showing social sharing option. But the problem is when I click the `.fa-share-alt` for individual post then it fires for all posts.

```
(function($) {
    "use strict";
    function initsocialShare(){
        $(".fa-share-alt").click(function(){
            $(".fa-share-alt").hide();
            $(".fa-times").show();
            $(".share").show();
        });
        $(".fa-times").click(function(){
            $(".fa-share-alt").show();
            $(".fa-times").hide();
            $(".share").hide();
        });
    }


    $(document).ready(function() {

        initsocialShare();

    });

})(jQuery);// End main function
```

**HTML CODE:**

```
<div class="share">
    <div class="widget-share">
        <!-- share-wrapper start -->
        <div class="share-wrapper">
            <!-- social start -->
            <div class="social">
                <i class="fa fa-facebook social-btn facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-facebook social-btn facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-facebook social-btn facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-facebook social-btn facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-facebook social-btn facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-facebook social-btn facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </div>
            <!-- social end -->
        </div>
        <!-- share-wrapper end -->
    </div>
</div>
<i id="<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="fa fa-share-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<i id="<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

Before click:
[image]

After click:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you use `$(".share")`, so it will target all elements which have class share. Click function in jQuery has parameter target as an eventObject, in which you can get the target has just click. After you got the target, you get the target's sibling element to show and hide, depend on what you need.

https://api.jquery.com/click/

https://api.jquery.com/siblings/

```
(function($) {
    "use strict";
    function initsocialShare(){
        $(".fa-share-alt").click(function(event){
            var target = $(event.target)
            target.hide();
            target.siblings('.fa-times').show();
            target.siblings('.share').show();
        });
        $(".fa-times").click(function(event){
            var target = $(event.target);
            target.hide();
            target.siblings('.fa-times').hide();
            target.siblings('.fa-share-alt').show();
            target.siblings('.share').hide();
        });
    }


    $(document).ready(function() {

        initsocialShare();

    });

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort but it shows this message:Uncaught TypeError: event.target.hide is not a function

Comment: @bdtheme just updated my answer, I mistake between javascript and jquery

Answer (score 0):

I figure out by changing HTML and jQuery codes as follows:

**HTML**

```
<div class="social-share-container">
                            <i id="<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="fa fa-share-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
                        <i id="<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        <span class="latest-news--comments" style="float: right;">
                            <i class="fa fa-comment" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            <?php printf( _nx( '', '%1$s', 'comments title', get_comments_number(), 'goalkick' ), number_format_i18n( get_comments_number() ) ); ?>
                        </span>
                        <div class="share"> 
                            <div class="widget-share">
                                <!-- share-wrapper start -->
                                <div class="share-wrapper">
                                    <!-- social start -->
                                    <div class="social">
                                        <i class="fa fa-facebook social-btn facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                    <i class="fa fa-facebook social-btn facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                    <i class="fa fa-facebook social-btn facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                    <i class="fa fa-facebook social-btn facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                    <i class="fa fa-facebook social-btn facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                    <i class="fa fa-facebook social-btn facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                    </div><!-- social end -->
                                </div><!-- share-wrapper end -->
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </div><!-- social-share-container end -->
```

**jQuery:**

```
function initsocialShare(){
        $(".social-share-container .fa-share-alt").click(function(){
            $(this).hide();
             $(this).siblings('.fa-times').show();
            $(this).siblings(".share").show();
        });
        $(".social-share-container .fa-times").click(function(){
            $(this).hide();
             $(this).siblings(".fa-share-alt").show();
             $(this).siblings(".share").hide();
        });
    }
```